# Google Query Language GQL string manipulation I need a REPLACE or SUBSTITUTE function

Tags: replace, google-sheets, gql, google-query-language

I'm using Google Sheets with an imported CSV.

The range I perform queries on is called 'Import'

I need to do simple string functions, like `REPLACE()` and `LEN()` to evaluate if the data I have is acceptable.

I've been searching, and cannot find any way to manipulate strings in Google Query Language?

Other sources suggest I can use 'Standard' SQL, but I don't seem to be able to?

Any ideas where to look and learn? This language doesn't seem well supported and I couldn't find any IRC groups either.

What I have:

```
=query(Import,"select A,B,F,E,AL where not AL matches '^[A-Za-z]{2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{3}$'")
```

What I want: (T-SQL)

```
=query(Import,"select A,B,F,E,AL where not REPLACE(AL," ","") matches '^[A-Za-z]{2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{3}$'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Google query language is very limited and there is no function that will give you the requested functionality. You should be able to perform the necessary replacements on your data *before* you run the query on them, though, using standard Google Sheets functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the data while defining the Query Range in the Query Formula itself, e.g.:

```
=query(ArrayFormula(regexreplace('Filters@0'!F1:L250,"Eliminate ","")),"select Col1, Col7 where Col7 matches '(.*\d{1,3}\.){3}.*'"))
```